# The Thank You message display twice in contact form 7 WordPress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

Need Javascript code for Prevent double form submission on double click.
See screenshot.
https://www.screencast.com/t/3SQ76CMVail

```
<script> jQuery(document).on('click', '.wpcf7-submit', function(e){
 if( jQuery('.ajax-loader').hasClass('is-active') ) {
 e.preventDefault(); return false; } 
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: I just tried it on the website shown on image and it works for me with no issues with a single message "Thank you for your message. It has been sent Successfully.".

Comment: when you double click it will be displayed.see screenshot.

https://www.screencast.com/t/3SQ76CMVail

Comment: I have found the solution brother, Just Added code in header.php

<script>
jQuery(document).on('click', '.wpcf7-submit', function(e){
     if( jQuery('.ajax-loader').hasClass('is-active') ) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
     }
});
</script>

Comment: You could add this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The first message shouldn’t be displayed as it’s just screen reader’s text and should be hidden by the plugin’s CSS. Maybe somehow some CSS is missing.

However, you can add this under Custom > CSS in the Customizer.

```
.screen-reader-response {
  display: none;
}
```

For The second thing, you can refer this [link](https://cfdbplugin.com/?page_id=904) to prevent Duplicate Submissions from CF7.

Hope this will helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/3SQ76CMVail

Answer (score 0):

Multiple from submissions are usually generated by users if they do not see a confirmation message immediately after clicking a form’s Send or Submit button. Sometimes the issue is related to slow form submissions, which are more of a server-related issue that is not under the control of a web site developer. With some sites, the Send or Submit button can be disabled using JavaScript, but that is not an option when using a plugin with WordPress. Neither plugins nor WordPress core code should be modified unless there are no other alternatives, The Contact Form 7 messages rely heavily on JQuery.

**Solution 1:**

There is a short piece of code that is added to the Additional Settings section on each Contact Form 7 editor page. You will find this section near the bottom of the editor page for each form that is created.

on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/request-submitted/';"

create a Page that contains a confirmation message. The user will be redirected to this page after submitting the form.

**Solution 2:**

There is a plugin to restrict cf7 multi click  (https://wordpress.org/plugins/stop-cf7-multiclick/), Refer FAQ section to How do i use the plugin?

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/w5X3zItMSN0  
The plugin is just Loading, Not submitting form.

Comment: Opp's, Then we can try some other way to prevent multi click using captcha, there is lots of free plugins available for capthca integration,  (https://wordpress.org/plugins/brandcaptcha-cf7/), it will help you

Comment: I have found the solution brother, Just Added code in header.php

<script>
jQuery(document).on('click', '.wpcf7-submit', function(e){
     if( jQuery('.ajax-loader').hasClass('is-active') ) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
     }
});
</script>